# Saving data in theme options page wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, serialization, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create dynamic rows in my theme option page and am trying to save those data in serialized data ..
[image: This is wat it looks]

As i add work experience new row is added ..Now I just want to save this values in serialized data and order them accordingly (may be by start date or serial no.)

> **MY JQUERY CODE**

```
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event) {
    alert("asdas");
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input style="width:200px" type="text" name="designation' + counter + '"/></td>
    <td><input style="width:200px" type="text" id="start_date' + counter +'" name="start_date' + counter + '"/></td>
    <td><input style="width:200px" id="end_date' + counter +'" type="text" name="end_date' + counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
    $("#start_date"+ counter).datepicker();
    $("#end_date"+ counter).datepicker();

});
```

> **My OPTIONS ARRAY**

```
array(
    "name" => "Designation",
    "desc" => "Enter your Designation of company.",
    "id" => $shortname."_designation",
    "type" => "workexp",
    "std" => ""
)
```

> **My HTML CODE FOR TYPE workexp**

```
case 'workexp':

?>
<a href="#" title="wrk_exp" class="add-author">Add Work Experience</a>
<table class="authors-list" border="1" bordercolor="#ddd" 
style="background-color:#F5F5F5" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr><td>Designation</td><td>StartDate</td><td>EndDate</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input style="width:200px" type="text" name="designation"/></td>
        <td><input style="width:200px" type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date"/></td>
        <td><input style="width:200px" type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
break;
```

> **MY CODE AFTER SAVE BUTTON**

```
if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {

    if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

        foreach ($options as $value) {
            update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] );
        }

        foreach ($options as $value) {
            if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) {
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  );
            } else {
                delete_option( $value['id'] );
            }
        }

        header("Location: admin.php?page=theme-options.php&saved=true");
        die;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your server end, you'll have to convert the values to an array first. Then [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) which will automatically serialize the data.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your PHP code that processes the form on the back end?

Comment: Based on what I can see, you are creating multiple input fields with the same name attribute. Your javascript needs to be adjusted to either give them names in sequential order (maybe using your counter variable) or to make them an array (i.e. designation[], start_date[]). Then you need to get them in your PHP script. Currently I don't see you grabbing them at all.